# refactoring duplicate javascript click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript click events. There is an indeterminate amount of `cat-#` classes. How can I best refactor this to avoid this code duplication as well as the ability to handle additional numbers that aren't hard coded?

```
$(document).on('click', '#browse-category .cat-1', function (e) {
    $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
    $('#browse-condition .cat-1').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).on('click', '#browse-category .cat-2', function (e) {
    $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
    $('#browse-condition .cat-2').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).on('click', '#browse-category .cat-3', function (e) {
    $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
    $('#browse-condition .cat-3').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).on('click', '#browse-category .cat-4', function (e) {
    $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
    $('#browse-condition .cat-4').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).on('click', '#browse-category .cat-5', function (e) {
    $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
    $('#browse-condition .cat-5').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

```
var setClickListener = function(target1, target2){
    $(document).on("click", target1, function (e) {
        $("#browse-condition li[class^='cat']").addClass("hidden");
        $("#browse-condition" + target2).removeClass("hidden");
    });
};
var baseSelector1 = "#browse-category .cat-";
var baseSelector2 = ".cat-";
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
       setClickListener(baseSelector + i, baseSelector2 +i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had to change a couple minor things to get this working. You're missing the ending `"` in the selector on line 3 and i had to change baseSelector2 to `" .cat-` to include the space and dot class notation

Comment: I made the fixes so it will be useful for someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is selecting all the items with the particular classname and then assigning click events to each of the elements, like so:

```js
var items = $("li[class^='cat']");

items.each(function() {
 $(this).on('click', function (e) {
  var cssClass = $(this).attr("class"); 
  $('#browse-condition li[class^="cat"').addClass('hidden');
  $('#browse-condition .' + cssClass).removeClass('hidden');
 });
})
```

This way you always get the right amount of clickevents.